# Can't upload binary to itunesconnect

Tags: app-store-connect

Can't upload application on itunesconnect during today. I have uploaded one application successful but can't upload other one (network connection error or request timeout). Is any solution for this or just wait till apple fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Seems like apple servers are down. The problem is usually solved after 3 or 4 hours

Comment: Yep. Temporary shortcuts in the iTunes upload process due to their servers is something usual. You don't see it everyday, but once in a while it happens...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was about a temporary server issue on Apple's side.

Comment: This is because there must be an issue with apple's servers. It will take around 3-4 hours before it is fixed in most cases.